# Matching binary file checksum between python and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, checksum

I need to manage checksum of image files downloaded from server. I have a config file which has imagefilepath and checksum of the file in JSON format as below:

```
{
"filepath": "/images/file.png",
"checksum": "dd37423ed23983442ddf232eab23b2b"
}
```

The checksum of the image file is generate at server (and added to this config file) using a python script as below:

```
import hashlib
f = open('file.png', 'rb')
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(f.read())
m.hexdigest()
```

The client app downloads the config file and then the image file. It then calculates the checksum of the image file in javascript using following code.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', fileurl, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var checksum = calculateChecksum(this.responseText);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

calculateChecksum uses [this algorithm](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-md5.html) to calculate checksum in javascript. But the problem is that checksum never matches with what is present in the config file (calculated from python code at server). The same works ok for text file. I am aware that in javascript string is encoded in UCS-2 format and that could be the reason the checksum is not calculated correctly.

Comment: Could it be that `responseText` is different from the image file in that is is encoded (Base64 or the like) or includes additional information such as http headers?

Comment: No, responseText does not contain HTTP header. PNG file format does contain MIME type at the beginning, but they will also be present when they are read in python.